# Can you make a pivot table by column index as opposed to column name in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a table composed of 400 rows and 35 columns, and made a VBA script to make a pivot table comparing 2 columns vs 12 separate columns successfully.

While generating the pivot table, column headers are used (to avoid confusion). I am new with VBA, and this is how I called everything up to my errors

```
ActiveCell.Select
Range("AA3").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Practitioners!R3C1:R246C27", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Practitioners!R3C29", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable8", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
Sheets("Practitioners").Select
Cells(3, 29).Select
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Capability")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Sub-Capability")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable8").PivotFields("Grade"), "Count of Grade", xlCount
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable8").PivotFields("06-Feb-2017"), "Count of 06-Feb-2017", xlCount
```

but my column headers will change every week, and altering the name of the header means the VBA code will not work because it is no longer "06-Feb-2017".

I tried making a reference to an absolute cell in my code, but came up with an error

> Run-time error '1004, Unable to get the PivotFields property of the
>   PivotTable class

Is there a way to refer to the `PivotFields` as an absolute cell reference (ie B3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below (explanations are inside the code comments).

You need to make sure that the formatting of Cell "B3" is identical to the one in the `PivotTable`, otherwise you will get a run-time error at the following line:

```
.AddDataField PvtTbl.PivotFields(PvtFlfVal), "Count of " & PvtFlfVal, xlCount
```

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DynamicPivotTableCountField()

Dim PvtTbl As Pivottable
Dim PvtFlfVal '   As String

' set the Pivot Table, replace "Sheet1" with your sheet's name (don't use ActiveSheet)
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Practitioners").PivotTables("PivotTable8")

' get the value from Cell B3, make sure it's formatted the way you need it for the Pivot Table later
PvtFlfVal = Format(Worksheets("Practitioners").Range("B3").Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

With PvtTbl
    .AddDataField PvtTbl.PivotFields(PvtFlfVal), "Count of " & PvtFlfVal, xlCount
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately I receive another run time error 1004: Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class on line 9 of your code (Set PvtTbl...)

Comment: @alex do you have the `PivotTable` set-up ? what is the worksheet name ? make sure the name of the `Worksheets` and PivotTable` match the code

Comment: @alex i've edited the code to match your `Worksheet` name